# xCode - exporting app (to .ipa) for Enterprise Deployment (with .p12 certificate)

Tags: ios, xcode, in-house-distribution

I'm a member of a team enrolled in the Apple Developer Enterprise program, I have the team agents .p12 distribution certificate in my keychain and the in-house provisioning profiles in place (which seems validated in the Project -> General tab, as no error displays). 
But when I try to Export for Enterprise Deployment, I get the error message:
"To save for Entryprise Deployment, you need to add an Apple ID account that is enrolled in the iOS Developer Program for the development team 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'"

I do not understand this error as I'm already a member of a team that is enrolled. I've tried a guide to export to ipa via the terminal but apparently it's dated since the commands have changed in newer version of xCode. So what can I do?, is there something the Team Agent can do? Do anybody know of a updated guide to export via terminal?

Hope you can help :-S

Comment: try to add your Apple ID in Xcode preferences

Comment: Thx for your feedback but my AppleID is already add'ed. I have already submitted apps to the appstore through this team, so the basics should be in place.. But with a new in-house-certificate, new in-house-provisionprofiles and then trying to export, it fails as mentioned above.

Comment: Silly question, but you’re part of their Enterprise Program right? Apple charges $299 annually for the “In-House” enterprise feature.

Comment: Well I was told so (first line in post) by the Team Agent (a company outsourced with the handling-assignment) when I asked after getting this error - turns out, she didn't know the difference and just said yes, even though they weren't.. So spot on..